# Use Xib with Scroll View - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, xib, nib

I try to use `Xib` files with `UIScrollView`. I set the constraints (top ,bottom ,leading ,trailing . equal width and height (**priority 250**)).

I added the `xibs` to view that inside of `UIScrollView`. And set the last element bottom anchor with `greaterThanOrEqualTo` .

But scrollview **not scroll** . Where is the problem ?

Thanks in advance.

```
@IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!
@IBOutlet weak var scrollViewSubView: UIView!

var campaignCollectionView:UICollectionView!
var pageControl:UIPageControl!
var winGiftVoucherCode:WinGiftVoucherView!
var lastCallDiscountView : LastCallDiscountView!

var lastCallDiscountView2 : LastCallDiscountView!
var lastCallDiscountView3 : LastCallDiscountView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    setupNavigationBarItems()
    setCollectionView()
    setPageControl()
    winGiftVoucherCodeFunc()
    lastCallDiscountFunc()

    lastCallDiscountFunc2()
    lastCallDiscountFunc3()

}



func setCollectionView(){

    let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    layout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
    let cCV = UICollectionView(frame: self.view.bounds, collectionViewLayout: layout)
    campaignCollectionView = cCV
    campaignCollectionView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    self.scrollViewSubView.addSubview(campaignCollectionView)

    campaignCollectionView.dataSource = self
    campaignCollectionView.delegate = self
    campaignCollectionView.backgroundColor = .white
    campaignCollectionView.isPagingEnabled = true
    campaignCollectionView.isScrollEnabled = true
    campaignCollectionView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false

    if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
        campaignCollectionView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollViewSubView.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
    } else {
        campaignCollectionView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.scrollViewSubView.topAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
    }

    if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
        campaignCollectionView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 150).isActive = true
        // campaignCollectionView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, constant: -10).isActive = true
    } else {
        campaignCollectionView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 150).isActive = true
        // campaignCollectionView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.bottomAnchor, constant: -10).isActive = true
    }

    if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
        campaignCollectionView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollViewSubView.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
    } else {
        campaignCollectionView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.scrollViewSubView.leadingAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
    }

    if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
        campaignCollectionView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollViewSubView.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor, constant: -10).isActive = true
    } else {
        campaignCollectionView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.scrollViewSubView.trailingAnchor, constant: -10).isActive = true
    }

    campaignCollectionView.register(UINib(nibName: "CampaignCollectionViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "CampaignCollectionViewCell")

}


func setPageControl(){
    let pC = UIPageControl()
    pageControl = pC
    pageControl.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    self.scrollViewSubView.addSubview(pageControl)

    if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
        pageControl.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: campaignCollectionView.bottomAnchor , constant: 10).isActive = true
    } else {
        pageControl.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: campaignCollectionView.bottomAnchor , constant: 10).isActive = true
    }

    if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
        pageControl.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 10).isActive = true
        // campaignCollectionView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, constant: -10).isActive = true
    } else {
        pageControl.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 10).isActive = true
        // campaignCollectionView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.bottomAnchor, constant: -10).isActive = true
    }

    if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
        pageControl.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollViewSubView.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
    } else {
        pageControl.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.scrollViewSubView.leadingAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
    }

    if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
        pageControl.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollViewSubView.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor, constant: -10).isActive = true
    } else {
        pageControl.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.scrollViewSubView.trailingAnchor, constant: -10).isActive = true
    }

    //pageControl.backgroundColor = .black
    //pageControl.tintColor = .white
    pageControl.pageIndicatorTintColor = .lightGray
    pageControl.currentPageIndicatorTintColor = .black

    pageControl.numberOfPages = 3
    pageControl.currentPage = 0
    //pageControl.hidesForSinglePage = true
}

func winGiftVoucherCodeFunc(){

    let wGVC : WinGiftVoucherView = UIView.fromNib()
    winGiftVoucherCode = wGVC
    winGiftVoucherCode.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    self.scrollViewSubView.addSubview(winGiftVoucherCode)

    if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
        winGiftVoucherCode.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: pageControl.bottomAnchor , constant: 10).isActive = true
    } else {
        winGiftVoucherCode.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: pageControl.bottomAnchor , constant: 10).isActive = true
    }

    if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
        winGiftVoucherCode.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 150).isActive = true
        // campaignCollectionView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, constant: -10).isActive = true
    } else {
        winGiftVoucherCode.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 150).isActive = true
        // campaignCollectionView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.bottomAnchor, constant: -10).isActive = true
    }

    if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
        winGiftVoucherCode.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollViewSubView.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
    } else {
        winGiftVoucherCode.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.scrollViewSubView.leadingAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
    }

    if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
        winGiftVoucherCode.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollViewSubView.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor, constant: -10).isActive = true
    } else {
        winGiftVoucherCode.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.scrollViewSubView.trailingAnchor, constant: -10).isActive = true
    }

    let rate : CGFloat = 0.85

    let mainRect = winGiftVoucherCode.frame
    let rec = winGiftVoucherCode.progressX.frame
    let aa = ProgressView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: ( mainRect.size.width - 100 ) * rate , height: rec.size.height) )
    aa.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
    self.winGiftVoucherCode.progressX.addSubview(aa)

    winGiftVoucherCode.voucherRemainderViewLeftConstraint.constant = ( winGiftVoucherCode.frame.width - 100 ) * rate - 20


}

func lastCallDiscountFunc(){

    let lCDV : LastCallDiscountView = UIView.fromNib()
    lastCallDiscountView = lCDV
    lastCallDiscountView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    self.scrollViewSubView.addSubview(lastCallDiscountView)

    if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
        lastCallDiscountView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: winGiftVoucherCode.bottomAnchor , constant: 10).isActive = true
    } else {
        lastCallDiscountView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: winGiftVoucherCode.bottomAnchor , constant: 10).isActive = true
    }

    if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
        lastCallDiscountView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 150).isActive = true
        // campaignCollectionView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, constant: -10).isActive = true
    } else {
        lastCallDiscountView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 150).isActive = true
        // campaignCollectionView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.bottomAnchor, constant: -10).isActive = true
    }

    if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
        lastCallDiscountView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollViewSubView.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
    } else {
        lastCallDiscountView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.scrollViewSubView.leadingAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
    }

    if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
        lastCallDiscountView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollViewSubView.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor, constant: -10).isActive = true
    } else {
        lastCallDiscountView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.scrollViewSubView.trailingAnchor, constant: -10).isActive = true
    }

}

func lastCallDiscountFunc2(){

    let lCDV : LastCallDiscountView = UIView.fromNib()
    lastCallDiscountView2 = lCDV
    lastCallDiscountView2.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    self.scrollViewSubView.addSubview(lastCallDiscountView2)

    if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
        lastCallDiscountView2.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: lastCallDiscountView.bottomAnchor , constant: 10).isActive = true
    } else {
        lastCallDiscountView2.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: lastCallDiscountView.bottomAnchor , constant: 10).isActive = true
    }

    if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
        lastCallDiscountView2.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 150).isActive = true
        // campaignCollectionView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, constant: -10).isActive = true
    } else {
        lastCallDiscountView2.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 150).isActive = true
        // campaignCollectionView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.bottomAnchor, constant: -10).isActive = true
    }

    if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
        lastCallDiscountView2.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollViewSubView.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
    } else {
        lastCallDiscountView2.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.scrollViewSubView.leadingAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
    }

    if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
        lastCallDiscountView2.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollViewSubView.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor, constant: -10).isActive = true
    } else {
        lastCallDiscountView2.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.scrollViewSubView.trailingAnchor, constant: -10).isActive = true
    }

}

func lastCallDiscountFunc3(){

    let lCDV : LastCallDiscountView = UIView.fromNib()
    lastCallDiscountView3 = lCDV
    lastCallDiscountView3.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    self.scrollViewSubView.addSubview(lastCallDiscountView3)

    if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
        lastCallDiscountView3.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: lastCallDiscountView2.bottomAnchor , constant: 10).isActive = true
    } else {
        lastCallDiscountView3.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: lastCallDiscountView2.bottomAnchor , constant: 10).isActive = true
    }

    if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
        lastCallDiscountView3.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 150).isActive = true
    } else {
        lastCallDiscountView3.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 150).isActive = true
    }

    if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
        lastCallDiscountView3.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollViewSubView.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
    } else {
        lastCallDiscountView3.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.scrollViewSubView.leadingAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
    }

    if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
        lastCallDiscountView3.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollViewSubView.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor, constant: -10).isActive = true
    } else {
        lastCallDiscountView3.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.scrollViewSubView.trailingAnchor, constant: -10).isActive = true
    }

    if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
        lastCallDiscountView3.bottomAnchor.constraint(greaterThanOrEqualTo: self.scrollViewSubView.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
    } else {
        lastCallDiscountView3.bottomAnchor.constraint(greaterThanOrEqualTo: self.scrollViewSubView.bottomAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, I **strongly** urge you to set up all your UI in XIBs/storyboards. It's so much easier to see what you're doing, rather than adding views programmatically.

If a scroll view doesn't scroll it probably means that its `contentSize` is smaller than its `frame`. It could also mean that you're blocking touches to it, which may be caused by your `UICollectionView`. Embedding a scrollable view inside a scrollable view will cause you headaches.

If you want to properly set up scroll views using autolayout I recommend following [this article](https://medium.com/@pradeep_chauhan/how-to-configure-a-uiscrollview-with-auto-layout-in-interface-builder-218dcb4022d7). The core principle is:

1. Add the scroll view to the VC's view and set its constraints to match the edges (leading/trailing/top/bottom) of the safe area.
2. Add a **content view** (`UIView`) whose constraints match the edges of the scroll view.
3. Set the **content view**'s `width` to match the `safeArea`'s `width` (assuming you want vertical scrolling, otherwise match the `height`s).
4. Add all your views to the **content view** and ensure that their constraints provide it with a fixed height (again, assuming you're going for vertical scrolling). That means having at least 1 view with a constraint to the top of the **content view**, and at least 1 with a constraint to its bottom, with set heights and vertical spaces in between.

It takes a while to learn how to do this properly, so be patient.

Comment: Thanks for repyly. I also applied all topics. But I didnt set contentsize because I give the last element constraint "greaterThanOrEqualTo" so I think no need the content size.

Comment: Unfortunately you can't have any `>=` heights if you want the scroll view to know the content size. If you really must have that then maybe set the **content view** height to match the safe area height, but then it kinda defeats the purpose of the scroll view...